# How to detect text selected by double clicking using Firefox SDK (for addons)?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, event-listener, double-click

User will double click on a word in the webpage and the addon should be able to listen to the event and get the selected text.

[What the SDK page for selection gives as an example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/selection):

```
get_definitions.port.on("text-entered", function (text) {
  console.log(text);
  text_entry.hide();
});

function myListener() {
  console.log(selection.text);
}
```

The thing is any kind of selection is detected. What I need is detection of text when it is selected by double clicking...

I was unable to figure out how to add a event listener that listens for a double click event on the webpage. Mind you:

```
addEventListener('dblclick', function);
```

wouldn't work because index.js of the addon cannot directly interact with the webpage. So it has to keep listening for a "double click" event provided through firefox SDK, but how to do it?

Comment: you can communicate between index.js and webpage .see [Communicating With  Other Scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Communicating_With_Other_Scripts) . also see this
you can do it without addon selection method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the addon has to get the selected text in a window:

The addon cannot directly manipulate the window or tab. I mean it can get details about it -- like list of all the tabs active, open a tab, get focus etc.

1. Attach a contentScript

But to truly work on a lower level as "getting the selected text" Firefox SDK provides "[Content Scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts)". They have to be attached to the target tab. We can attach the Content Script "someScript.js" in two ways:

You can directly attach using [tabs API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs) :

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

tabs.on('activate', function(tab) {
  var worker = tab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: data.url("someScript.js")
  });
});
```

or you can use [PageMod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) :

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.mozilla.org",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("someScript.js")
});
```

There is indeed a difference between using Tabs API and PageMod API:

Tabs API : You get to decide to which tab the contentScript is attached based on different criteria(which tab, which state etc).

PageMod API : Attaches to all the pages with a matching URL pattern.

Now the attached contentScript acts like it's a part of the page it is attached to.

2. Do stuff with someScript.js:

In this case get the selected text by double click:

```
//someScript.js
document.addEventListener('dblclick', function(){
        var selObj = window.getSelection();
        oRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
        var selectedText = selObj.toString();

        console.log(selectedText);
}, false);
```

3. Communication between contentScript and main.js (addon):

As you can see the contentScript just prints the selected text to the console. To communicate the same to the Addon or main.js or index.js we need to [make use of the "port" object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port).

Tabs API:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

tabs.on('activate', function(tab) {
  var worker = tab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: data.url("someScript.js")
  });

  //Keep listening on the port named "selectedText" from someScript.js
  worker.port.on("selectedText", function(sText) {
      console.log(sText);
  });
});
```

PageMod API:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.mozilla.org",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("someScript.js"),

  //Keep listening on the port named "selectedText" from someScript.js
  onAttach: function(worker) {
      worker.port.on("selectedText", function(sText) {
          console.log(sText);
      });
  }
});
```

Send messages from contentScript to main.js:

```
//someScript.js
document.addEventListener('dblclick', function(){
        var selObj = window.getSelection();
        oRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
        var selectedText = selObj.toString();

        console.log(selectedText);

        //emit the selected text on port named "selectedText"
        self.port.emit("selectedText", selectedText);
}, false);
```